# Walkie talkie open source library on iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8

I have to do two way walkie talkie iOS app.. I searched a lot got information about 'push to talk service'. But can't get clear idea. May anyone can help me? How it works by iPhone for a particular channel... I got a iTunes link

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/two-way-walkie-talkie/id595560554?mt=8

Can anyone tell me how this app works? Is they recorded and send voices to other user or they are sending live audio ? Also they are not getting any information from user..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most walkie talkie apps are done by sending recorded audio file instead of sending live audio stream.

If you want to implement a record-and-forward type walkie talkie, you need to have a backend file server for storing temporary audio files which can be downloaded by the receiver side.

If you choose the hard way, i.e, sending live audio stream, it's another level of complexity. You're look at implementing literally a VOIP app. You may use [PJSIP](http://www.pjsip.org) for your VOIP core functionality. However, you might end up spending months on the project in this case.

Personally, I strongly recommend you to go with the first one.

Comment: Is there any open source library available for iOS ?

Comment: I'm not sure about open source library for record-and-forward type walkie talkie. However, it's not difficult to make one by yourself. You can use AVFoundation framework [tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-avfoundation-framework-tutorial/) for recording and playing back audio files. For backend file server solution, it's easiest/quickest/most reliable to use Amazon Web Services, i.e [S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/), however, it's not free. You can also choose to use [Parse](https://www.parse.com), not free either. Those backends are well adopted and relative cheep if you don't have your own.

Comment: Thanks for your information. do you know about push to talk api? is there any open source for this?

Comment: I don't know any open source project for this, nothing I have personally tried. I found https://www.openhub.net/p/walkietalkie in google. Anyway, if you read the tutorial and links I mentioned above. You can get more idea on how to do it on your own in no time.

Comment: yes i got it. But when we record and forward audio gets delayed in other end. I don't want to expect like a phone call. But when user select a particular channel and starts speaking, other side who ever waiting on same channel getting audio frequently without any delay. Thats what i expect. Is it possible to streaming audio to server while user recording their audio through iPhone?

Comment: In that case, you may look into PJSIP for details. You actually wanted a solution between VOIP and record-and-forward audio, there're too many possible solutions, you need to do more research, so that you find some solution feasible for your time frame of the development.